# Java Play2.3: object controllers.Map is not a value

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

Building a java application using Playframework 2.3.6 with jdk1.8

When attempting to compile my application (using "activator ~run"), the following error is thrown:

```
/website/conf/routes:12: object controllers.Map is not a value
[error] GET     /assets/*file      controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
```

My routes file is the following:

```
# Home page
GET     /                       controllers.Application.home()
POST    /                       controllers.Application.resultsPage()

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file           controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

I've tried adjusting things all over the application and searching the web, but have had no luck figuring out what seems to be a fairly basic issue. Not really sure where to begin, so please let me know if more information is needed.

UPDATE:

The closest I've found to "information" about this on the internet is that a similar "object Map is not a value" error shows up when someone is importing the Java Map function into a scala file. And while I am using the Map function in certain controllers, I can't see where that would be conflicting with Scala or where I'm wrong importing the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have sort of solved this, and it's related to the comment I made about the scala map function.

The error, while indicating a line in the routes file, is actually being thrown by the reverse routing that is being compiled by the framework (namely, routes_reverseRouting.scala). There is a map going on there that for whatever reason was being read as a java map instead of a scala map. In order to temporarily fix this, I imported the scala immutable map function directly into that ReverseAssets class and it compiled (unfortunately, this is a bandaid solution, as if you needed to recompile the routes file, it would overwrite this).

I happened to be simultaneously refactoring my controllers and the issue disappeared by itself.